How can I continously send messages from an Android Service to the currently running activity , even when the service is busy
I have a running service which performs a long running operation, the user can initiate the service with a press of a button from an activity, which will show a loading spinner and disable all controls except back, if the user navigates back they can reenter this screen, and I need it to show the loading spinner and disable the buttons, unfortunately due to some technical issues I can not use a binding service, the service has to have a one way communication with my activity using broad casts. The following is some sample code of how my service works currently
fun startWorking() {
    serviceScope //this is a scope I created that will cancel when the service is destroyed
       .launch {
          sendBroadcast(UploadServiceState.Gathering)
          val dataToSend = gatherData()
          sendBroadcast(UploadServiceState.Sending)
          val reply = retrofitClient.sendData(dataToSend) //this part may take anywhere from 1 to 14 seconds currently)
          sendBroadcast(UploadServiceState.Saving)
          saveReply(reply)
          sendBroadcast(UploadServiceState.Finished)
    }
}

I need the service to continuously send the Sending message while I am waiting for the reply from the retrofit client, the only way I have found to do this so far is
fun startWorking() {
    val state = AtomicReference<UploadServiceState>(UploadServiceState.None)
    serviceScope.launch {
        while(true) {
            val currentState = state.get()
            sendBroadCast(currentState)
            if (currentState == UploadServiceState.Finished)
                break
            delay(250)
        }
    }
    serviceScope 
       .launch {
          state.set(UploadServiceState.Gathering)
          val dataToSend = gatherData()
          state.set(UploadServiceState.Sending)
          val reply = retrofitClient.sendData(dataToSend) //this part may take anywhere from 1 to 14 seconds currently)
          state.set(UploadServiceState.Saving)
          saveReply(reply)
          state.set(UploadServiceState.Finished)
    }
}

is there a better way to do the above?
